# Possible to have different theme in Firefox and Firefox Developers Edition?

Tags: ubuntu, firefox

Is it possible to have a different THEME in firefox and firefox developers edition?

I have both running simultaneously and have separate profiles (separate history/saved logins/bookmarks/etc) but this theme seems to be shared between both and I need to visually separate them.

I doubt that it matters, but I'm running Ubuntu 22.04. Firefox (regular) is the snap edition, developer edition is installed from a tar file.

Comment: Things like this often depend on the app's identification with the system & whether the two share the same prefs location. idk nix well enough to know where to track that info down. If the OS doesn't differentiate, then usually the only time it can be set is *before* compile.

Comment: If you add MozillaTeam as ppa, and install directly from ppa using apt, does that give another option for theme, to easily distinguish which version you're using? https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

Comment: I tried installing firefox via ppa but it doesn't want to open now. Every time I click on the shortcut (or via cli) it opens developers edition. What a mess...